# Always getting error when cart is empty, Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, cart

Facing this error:

> ErrorException in CartController.php line 35: Trying to get property of non-object

This is the code:

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->data['details'] = Cart::content();

        $this->data['shipping'] = Shipping::where('region_category_id',session('location'))->where('type',session('type_komoditi'))->first();

        $regType = session('regType');

        $regId = session('id_wilayah');
        $qReg = RegionCategory::find($regId);
        if($regType == 'children') {
          $this->data['minimalWeight'] = $qReg->minimal_weight;
          //$this->data['minimalBuy'] = $qReg->min_buy;

        }
        $this->data['minimalBuy'] = $qReg->min_buy; //this is line 35
        $this->data['regType'] = $regType;

        \Session::put('price',Cart::total());
        \Session::put('totalPrice',Cart::total());
        \Session::put('paycode',0);

        return view('client.carts.index',$this->data);
    }
```

when I delete the line 35 the error is gone, but that code is important for using minimal buy filter.
How to resolve this error?

Comment: what is $this->data ? And which line is line 35 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's error cause **$qReg->min_buy** return null. 
You can fix by return default value like this:

```
$this->data['minimalBuy'] = $qReg->min_buy ?? 0;
```

That's mean if is **null** return 0

Comment: umm sorry, but when i try in staging server this error appear: local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'syntax error, unexpected '?'' in /home/paskomnas-dev/www/app/Http/Controllers/Client/CartController.php:38

Answer (score 0):

It's saying that $qReg is not an object and you are trying to get the value from it using `min_buy` property.

Try printing the object `$qReg` using `print_r($qReg);` and exit the script after that.

```
print_r($qReg);
exit();
```

And check whether that object has the property `min_buy` or not.

Why is `$this->data['minimalBuy'] = $qReg->min_buy;` after if block ? It's being overwritten even if `if($regType == 'children')` is false.